# non-uniform distributed random array

Tags: python, random

I need to generate a vector of random float numbers between [0,1] such
that their sum equals 1 and that are distributed non-uniformly.
Is there any python function that generates such a vector?

Best wishes

Comment: You need to specify better what distribution you need. As an extreme case, you could generate nine numbers in the range [0,0.001] then subtract the sum of them from 1 to get the tenth. That certainly meets your criteria but it seems a little artificial so you should beef up those criteria somewhat.

Comment: An improvement to @paxdiablo's method is to generate n numbers in any range and then divide each of them with the sum of the vector. That would give a vector with sum 1. The distribution is another matter though.

Comment: I presume that the numbers being "distributed non-uniformly" means that the numbers should not all be (roughly) equal - I have given an answer below according to this assumption. If this is not what you meant, please clarify your question, as even a fixed vector containing, say `[0.05, 0.2, 0.3, 0.45]` in some random order satisfies your criteria: it is random, non-uniform and sums up to 1.

Comment: You mean "uniformly" in this case, not "non-uniformly"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The distribution you are probably looking for is called the [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). There's no built-in function in Python for drawing random numbers from a Dirichlet distribution, but [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) contains one:

```
>>> from numpy.random.mtrand import dirichlet
>>> print dirichlet([1] * n)
```

This will give you *n* numbers that sum up to 1, and the probability of each such combination will be equal.

Alternatively, if you don't have NumPy, you can make use of the fact that a random sample drawn from an *n*-dimensional Dirichlet distribution can be generated by drawing *n* independent samples from a [gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with shape and scale parameters equal to 1 and then dividing the samples with the sum:

```
>>> from random import gammavariate
>>> def dirichlet(n):
...     samples = [gammavariate(1, 1) for _ in xrange(n)]
...     sum_samples = sum(samples)
...     return [x/sum_samples for x in samples]
```

The reason why you need a Dirichlet distribution is because if you simply draw random numbers uniformly from some interval and then divide them by the sum of them, the resulting distribution will be biased towards samples consisting of roughly equal numbers. See [Luc Devroye's book](http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~luc/rnbookindex.html) for more on this topic.

Comment: Great! Please consider marking the solution as "accepted" if you are satisfied with this one.

Comment: Why not use the simpler `random.expovariate`?

Comment: Sure, `random.expovariate` is fine as well in this case; the only reason I prefer to use `random.gammavariate` is that it works even in the more general case when the Dirichlet distribution has different `alpha` parameters along different dimensions. The scenario described by Javier corresponds to the case when every `alpha` parameter in the Dirichlet distribution is 1.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nicer example in [Wikipedia page: Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution).
The code below generate a k dimension sample:

```
params = [a1, a2, ..., ak]
sample = [random.gammavariate(a,1) for a in params]
sample = [v/sum(sample) for v in sample]
```